# Assign Tasks to Users based on Job Title in another list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a list called `Contacts` which stores names and job titles.

I also have a list called `Project Tasks` which is a list of all project tasks. In this list, I have a choice field called `Assigned To Title` in which multiple job titles can be chosen.

I would like to be able to dynamically assign names from `Contacts` to tasks in `Project Tasks` based on

```
if 'Assigned To Title' contains 'Job Title' from 'Contacts'
```

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010 and I have the workflow working for tasks assigned to just one Job Title. I'm using update list item. I need a way to concate names on tasks that are assigned to two or more job titles.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is tricky to implement. For similar requirement the best practice is to use Event Receivers.

Here are the steps you should create

1. Iterate through the selected contacts
2. Create a loop
3. For each contact, get the title and concatenate into a workflow variable
4. Once the loop is finished, update the variable value into the corresponding list item field

Use https://spdwfstringactions.codeplex.com/ to iterate through the selected contacts. You need to use `IndexOf` and `SubString`

Creating a loop https://brianscodingexamples.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/create-while-loop-within-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/